# SQL Statement in VB to Join w/ Area Code

Tags: sql, vb.net

So first I have 2 tables-

1. Main Output Table
2. Geocode Replacement/Correction Table

First thing we do is a leftjoin - if main output table matches any geocodes on replacement table, it swaps them out.

However we have 3 columns in main output table where the geocodes can go:

1. zipCity
2. zipState
3. zipNation

This determines a lot of factors depending on where the geocode is placed.

Now the kicker: The geocode replacement table has 2 exceptions where although the geocode is city related, it needs to go to state. They are special exceptions. So I made a checkbox to mark them.

For these exceptions that are checkbox'd - I want the SQL/SELECT statement to check if the checkbox is checked, and if so - mark it as a ZIPSTATE. If it is not marked, keep it as a ZIPCITY.

My Biggest problem: With the below SELECT coding, it keeps giving me a syntax error complaining about an operator. But I have triple checked this a million times, and I really am under the impression that it doesn't like multiple AS [Column Name] statements in a single column select.

```
qdQuery.SQL = "SELECT IIf(Input.ZIPCITY Is Not Null, IIf(Input.ZIPCITY=[Geocodes].
    [ReplaceGeocode],IIf([Geocodes].[ExceptionChkBox],[Geocodes]![ReplacementGeocode] 
    AS [ZIP STATE], [Geocodes]![ReplacementGeocode] AS [ZIP CITY]), Input.ZIPCITY AS 
     [ZIP CITY]), Input.GEOCITY As [ZIP CITY])" _
    & " FROM  Input LEFT JOIN [Geocodes] ON Input.ZIPCITY=[Geocodes].[ReplaceGeocode] 
       Or Input.ZIPSTATE=[Geocodes].[ReplaceGeocode] Or Input.ZIPNATION=[Geocodes].
      [ReplaceGeocode]"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please read this on how to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/faq  You should encase your SQL code in a code section so it is more readable.   What is the error message?

Comment: i'm happy to format the code :)

Comment: I already did reformat it. As soon as the re-formatting is approved you'll see it.

Comment: Shouldn't `[Geocodes]![ReplacementGeocode]` be `[Geocodes].[ReplacementGeocode]`?

Comment: Sorry for the newbie-ness in formatting my code!

The error I am getting is: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression <Insert Quote for entire SELECT Statement> Error Code: 3075"

Comment: DBMS being used is a recordset in VBA Access for reference.

Comment: I see a lot of IIf( but not a lot of closing ")"

Comment: Hi Lotus - Not sure if it was when the code was revised for formatting, but all of the IIF Statements have closings ")" after the AS [ZIP CITY]) statements.

Comment: Copy and paste the SQL into your SQL Engine and see if it runs.

Comment: Yatrix: Sadly... I don't have any simple SQL Engine, only Access VBA SQL. I don't happen to have Visual Studio or any live SQL Server.

Comment: @user2296381: Did you try replacing the exclamation mark in `[Geocodes]![ReplacementGeocode]`?

Comment: Hi Ricahrd, I believe the exclamation point is part of the correct syntax for cell replacement - I did change it as you requested to a period, it still spit out the same error :(

Comment: @user2296381: I think I see the problem - you're trying to set different column names within an `IIF` call. One column can't have different names for different records.

Comment: Thanks Richard - as I said in the original post however, that was kind of what I suspsected. My problem is that I don't know another way to apply it. Basically the condition I am testing (the checkbox) determines which column it needs to be placed in.

Do you have an alternative for placing in different columns depending on these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with Access, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    IIf(Input.ZIPCITY Is Not Null, 
        IIf(Input.ZIPCITY=[Geocodes].[ReplaceGeocode],
            IIf([Geocodes].[ExceptionChkBox],
                Null, 
                [Geocodes]![ReplacementGeocode]
            ), 
            Input.ZIPCITY), 
        Input.GEOCITY
    ) As [ZIP CITY],

    IIf(Input.ZIPCITY Is Not Null, 
        IIf(Input.ZIPCITY=[Geocodes].[ReplaceGeocode],
            IIf([Geocodes].[ExceptionChkBox],
                [Geocodes]![ReplacementGeocode],
                Null
            ), 
            Null), 
        Null
    ) As [ZIP STATE]
FROM
    Input 
    LEFT JOIN [Geocodes] 
    ON Input.ZIPCITY = [Geocodes].[ReplaceGeocode] 
    Or Input.ZIPSTATE = [Geocodes].[ReplaceGeocode] 
    Or Input.ZIPNATION = [Geocodes].[ReplaceGeocode]
```